# webkit loses transition animation when parent is temporarily hidden with display none

Tags: css, css-transitions

It seems that when we change the display property of the parent element of a transitioning child, in webkit the animation on the child stops - and when the display of the element is reverted back, the child styles are displayed as if the transition has finished/the css transition property does not exist.

in firefox, the transition continues uninterrupted, as if the element continued transitioning even if the parent (and the inner element) were temporarily hidden

here's a replication of the issue: https://tinker.io/95219/1 animate, then hide show while the rectangle is transitioning. try in firefox and webkit to see the difference

is this a known bug?

Comment: Tinker seems to be either **dead** or **down**. Can you put the same code in JSFiddle and also copy it in your question so it's available to general public even when third party services fail.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik tinker is donw so i cant get the code. will make sure to add the code in the question in the future though!

Answer (score 3):

Using `visibility: hidden;` instead of `display: none;` seems to work.

Like so: https://tinker.io/95219/3

```
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

If you want to emulate `display: none;` (i.e. as if the element is indeed completely hidden), you could set the height to zero, like so: https://tinker.io/95219/4 (Had to target `#container` rather than `#parent` to achieve this.

```
#container.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
}
```

Comment: im afraid thats not possible :( real-world scenario im using this with jquery mobile and the #parent is the page the transition is occuring on, ie we change pages and that is where display: none is used (by jqmobile), and when i come back to the page, the animation should continue

Comment: i would have to change the jquery mobile plugin code which is not something i want to mess with especially for this unlikely scenario

Comment: `display: none` does not only visually remove the element from the DOM. It removes it completely. For example, it also removes it from the tab order. So `visibility: hidden` is only visually similar to it.

Comment: @tobib `display: none` does not remove the element in any way. It's still available in the DOM. It does hide the element in such a way that it can not interfer with the flow.

Comment: @BramVanroy fair point. But still `display: none` hides much more of an element than just its visibility.